# InputStream via ReadableByteChannel does not read to end

Tags: java, inputstream, nio, channel

I have an existing problem where I am using InputStreams and I want to increase the performance of reading from this channel. Therefore i read with a `ReadableByteChannel`.

As a result the reading is much faster with this code:

```
public static String readAll(InputStream is, String charset, int size) throws IOException{

    try(ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
        java.nio.ByteBuffer buffer = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(size);

        try(ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(is)){

            int bytesRead = 0;

            do{
                bytesRead = channel.read(buffer);
                bos.write(buffer.array(), 0, bytesRead);
                buffer.clear();
            }
            while(bytesRead >= size);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        String ans = bos.toString(charset);
        return ans;
    }
}
```

The Problem is: **It does not read to the end every time!** If I try to read a File it works pretty good. If I read from a network Socket (to request a WebPage manually for example) it sometimes stops somewhere in between.

What can I do to read to the end?

I don't want to use something like this:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
while(true){
    int ans = is.read();
    if(ans == -1) break;
    result.append((char)ans);
}
return result.toString();
```

because this implementation is slow.

I hope you can help me with my problem. maybe i have some mistake in my code.

Comment: Err... Do not use a `StringBuilder` to store binary data!

Comment: Also, why do you believe that using a `ReadableByteChannel` will increase performance at all? Plain `InputStream` implementations are plenty fast already

Comment: I used the second implementation before and it was really slow for reading long http responses and files (don't know why). Until now I simply used this method for texts - that's why the methods return a String and use StringBuilder.

Comment: Reading and processing one byte at a time is always slow. You're comparing apples and oranges here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your copy loop is completely wrong. There's no reason why `bytesRead` should *ever* be `>= size`, and it misbehaves at end of stream. It should be something like this:

```
while ((bytesRead = channel.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    bos.write(buffer.array(), 0, bytesRead);
    buffer.clear();
}
```

with suitable adjustments for limiting the transfer to `size` bytes, which are non-trivial.

But layering all this over an existing `InputStream` cannot possibly be 'much faster' tha using the `InputStream` directly, unless because of the premature termination. Unless your idea of use an `InputStream` is what you posted, which is horrifically slow. Try that with a '`BufferedInputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

This causes problem:

```
    ... } while (bytesRead >= size);
```

Reading from socket may return when at least one byte was read (or even if no bytes in case of non-blocking). So if there are not enough bytes in OS socket buffer, the condition will break the loop although obviously not full content was read. If the `size` identifies expected length to be received, implement `total += bytesRead` and break the loop when `total` reaches `size`. Or if you reach end of file of course...